# Angular subscribe won't update when data changes

Tags: angular, typescript, rest, ionic-framework

I have a subscribe in typescript that pulls locations from my own ASP.NET database. However, they only pull the data once, but the locations should be updated live. How do I get my Observable to automatically update?

I've tried to use ChangeDetectorRef, but it didn't solve the issue (neither *.MarkForCheck()* or *.DetectChanges()*).

```
getLocations(){
        console.log("Get them all!"); 
        this.API.getAllLocations().subscribe(result =>{
            this.locations = result;
            console.log(this.locations);
            this.addLocationMarkers();
            this.ref.markForCheck();
        });
}

getAllLocations(): Observable<Location[]> {
    return this._http.get<Location[]>(this.url + "location/", this.headers);
}
```

I can clearly see that *console.log(this.locations)* is only called once in my browser. Why isn't it called when the underlying data changes in the database?

Comment: This is not how `http` requests work. When it completes, it is closed. If you want realtime updates, you might want to look at web sockets: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)

Comment: Whenever there's an update that took place on your database, it will not affect you're current data unless you'd call and subscribe to its corresponding http call. I agree to what Harun said that you might be looking for a Web Sockets, you might want to use socket.io or others.

Comment: So what I did in *getAllLocations()* is not a subscribe to a http call?

Comment: Also, I was under the impression that it was the subscription on an Observable that would watch out for any changes? Is this not the case then? @KShewengger

Comment: It watches for changes to the stream. But as @HarunYılmaz mentioned, after an Http request completes, it is closed. So you won't receive any further notifications from the stream. Unlike other streams (such as mouse move or user typing events), Http request/responses are "one and done".

Comment: @MyNameIsGuzse Yes it is and would update your data based on the caller's response but it would not dynamically update them if the data just took place on your database without an immediate interaction or call with the front-end or angular side through another http call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this can be done using Rxjs library

in your ts file

```
import "rxjs/Rx";


numberSubscription: Subscription;

getLocations(){
console.log("Get them all!"); 
const data = Observable.interval(10000).startWith(0); <= this is the time interval in ms at which you want check for change of data in database.
    this.numberSubscription = data.subscribe((number: number) => {
        this.API.getAllLocations().subscribe(result =>{
                    this.locations = result;
                    console.log(this.locations);
                    this.addLocationMarkers();
                    this.ref.markForCheck();
                });
    });
  }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I think there is more than one issues bothering here. First, there is nested subscriptions which `rxjs` discourages to do so. You can avoid it using `pipe` and one of `map` operators. Second, this is not actual realtime, this is `polling`that will keep sending http request every 10 seconds. And I think this not what @MyNameIsGuzse is asking for.

Comment: in that case we can use like  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.numberSubscription.unsubscribe();
   
  }  this will work only when the component is rendered and wont subscribe to api when it is no needed