# Automatically update table in Angular, when another user adds something

Tags: angular, mongodb, mongoose

How to detect in Angular that the collection in MongoDB has been modified? I have a ngx-datatable component. The table gets an array of objects from MongoDB database. I want to automatically update the table **when another user** adds a new object. I know how to do this using Socket.io. Is there any other way than sockets? I use Node.js as the backend and Mongoose library.

Comment: You cannot doing this without websockets

Comment: this can be achived by using rxjs library. Refer the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54124555/angular-subscribe-wont-update-when-data-changes/54125186#54125186